# How to generate a pair of unchecked radio buttons with Thymeleaf and Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I want to create a pair of unchecked radio buttons with Thymeleaf and Spring. Therefor I use the attribute `th:field`. This will bind the properties of a bean (model) to the input fields. No matter how I configure the input fields always one of them is checked, e.g. setting the `th:checked` attribute to `false` at both `input` tags: `<input type="radio" th:field="*{property}" th:checked="false" />`.

I know the radio buttons have to be such always one options is selected by default. This is the way. But the user should be forced to choose one of the options and I don't want to use custom javascript to get this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radio button is selected if its `value` matches the `th:field`.  I'm not sure what this is supposed to be matching, since there is no value.

```
<!-- From your code -- there is no value -->
<input type="radio" th:field="*{property}" th:checked="false" />
```

That said, if you are using a `boolean`, it only has 2 states -- true and false so if there are 2 radio buttons, one is always checked.  If you want to use a `boolean` property and have the radio buttons start unchecked simply use a `Boolean` (which can be true, false or NULL) instead of a `boolean`.  This works for me for example:

Java

```
class Form {

  private Boolean property;

  public Boolean getProperty() {
    return property;
  }

  public void setProperty(Boolean property) {
    this.property = property;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<form th:object="${form}">
  <input type="radio" value="true" th:field="*{property}" /> - yes<br />
  <input type="radio" value="false" th:field="*{property}" /> - no<br />
</form>
```